# stacked line/area graph in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, visualization, stacked-area-chart, stream-graph

I have a question regarding matplotlib and I already know that what I am doing is not statistically / mathematically correct in a way but I want visualize anyways using stacked line / area graphs.

The measurements I have do not use the same x axis as a basis. I mean the different lines does not have the same number of data points. I want to use time as x axis and the measurements taken are not related to exact same timestamps (think distributed systems).

I guess my question is: "can I do that in matplotlib without doing the interpolation myself?"

here some indeepth elaboration about what a stacked graph is:
http://www.leebyron.com/else/streamgraph/download.php?file=stackedgraphs_byron_wattenberg.pdf

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: Is it correct that you have pairs of arrays `x`,`y`, where different pairs have different `x`-s? Then use `plot(x,y)` for each pair and you're done. If it's something else you're about, please elaborate.

Comment: as I said I am trying to create stacked graphs (http://www.chartingcontrol.net/gallery/StackedLine.png). Of cause I can interpolate myself the measurements, add them in order to get a stack and use plot(x, y). I wounder if there is already something in matplotlib that I can use to do the same.

Comment: currently it looks like I am going to use numpy.interp to do the interpolation. In this way the code will still be slim

Comment: Yeah, to the best of my knowledge and understanding, that's something you'd have to DIY. Which makes sence, as it's not really about programming, it's more about what your data means--- which a software can't do.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably not quiet understanding exactly what you want to do, but what about switching the axis so that your x-axis becomes the y-axis and then you can use something like whats suggested here [Multiple overlapping plots with independent scaling in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647443/multiple-overlapping-plots-with-independent-scaling-in-matplotlib) for multiple y-axis?

Comment: this has nothing to do with stacked line / area graphs :-(

Comment: I guess my suggestion was that if you are trying to interpolate your x axis data onto the same basis, matplotlib can already do this for the y-axis by having different scaling there, so why not turn the graph around? Just a suggestion.